# How to fix a div inside another element which contains scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a div of `height:x; width:y; overflow:auto;` which displays the content of an article.
Naturally, as the content extends beyond the constraints of the div, a scrollbar will appear to let me read through all the content.

The div contains a 'close' link `position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 20px;` which displays an 'x' to close the div (using jQuery & animations).
The problem is, as I scroll through the article, the 'x' also scrolls with it.  I want the 'x' to remain in the same position rather than move with the content.

I've tried changing the position value to 'fixed' but that fixes it to the body of the page, not the div.  How can I overcome this without positioning the div outside the main content?

```
<div class="box1">
  <a data-type="close">X</a>
  <div class="inner">
      //content//
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Create an inner div and let that div house the content and do the scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the wrapper div the same size as the inner scrolling div and add `position:relative;` Then position the close button absolutely within the wrapper div and increase the z-index so it is above the inner div.

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/seZ6V/1/)

The code (based on your html):

```
.box1 {
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}

.inner {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    overflow:auto;
}

a {
    top:0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: The `<a>` doesn't need a `z-index` becuase it is positioned, therefore it is in a different stacking context than the `.inner`

Comment: Oops, you are right. Forgot to remove it from when I was experimenting.

Comment: P.S. sorry if it seems I copied your answer (I didn't) but I had already written it and decided to submit it anyway. Great minds think alike :)

Comment: That worked pretty much.  Just a few minor changes because I didn't give you the full code... Don't really know why I didn't try that :/ ty

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you already know you can do this, but I think putting the `overflow: auto;` on the `.inner` div is the only way:

```
.box1 {
    background: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
a[data-type="close"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/36U4R/

Answer (score 0):

Apply position on close a tag:

```
<a data-type="close" style="position:fixed;">X</a>
```

Hope this help

Comment: This was mentioned as something the OP tried, but as he said it attaches the `<a>` to the body of the page, not to the `<div>`

Comment: As Michael states, `position:fixed` will always place things relative to the viewport, not an inner HTML element. Also, no reason to use inline CSS here.